# Can't create tables via Doctrine cli

Tags: php, doctrine

I try to create tables via doctrine cli:

cli-config.php

```
<?php
require_once "bootstrap.php";
return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = true;
$proxyDir = null;
$cache = null;
$useSimpleAnnotationReader = false;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode, $proxyDir, $cache, $useSimpleAnnotationReader);

$conn = array(
    'dbname' => 'project',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '123456',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql'
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

sample table (src/Product.php)

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

But in any cli commands (vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create) I take:

**[OK] No Metadata Classes to process.**

The same situation if I try to create table via xml or yaml. As if the script does not see any files. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is `bootstrap.php` located in your project root? If not, the first argument to `Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` is perhaps providing an invalid path mapping to your entities (`__DIR__. '/src'` expects `bootstrap.php` to be in your project root directory).

Comment: Yes, sure. All other doctrine functions works fine (I can create data, update, etc). But I can't create tables by the cli (create it manually).